# Django, suiting model structure

Tags: django, django-models

Hi can't figure out a suitable data structure for my models. These are my requirements:

- Each **UserModel** is represents a single **Referee**
- A **RefereeTeam** is made of two Referees
- One **Game** can have one referee or a RefereeTeam
- A **Referee** or a RefereeTeam can request any Game (to supervise it)
- Each Game can have arbitrary **Requests**
- Each Game can have only one appointed Referee or Team
- **States** are ('Declined', 'Open', 'Appointed') for each request

My current models are just not maintainable.

------ **EDITED FROM HERE** ------
[image]

From the *n* GameRequests only one will become the appointment. And if for some reason (life) the appointment becomes invalid I need to be able to pick someone of the other GameRequests for the specific game.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django_filters import FilterSet

from users.models import CustomUser # AUTH_MODEL!



class Hall(models.Model):
    """PLACE OF GAME"""
    # details


class team(models.Model):
    name, etc.


class Game(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='home')
    gast = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='team')
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Halle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.heim == self.gast:
            raise ValidationError(_("..."))

class RefTeam(models.Model):
    sr1 = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='gsr1',
        null=True,
        blank=True)
    sr2 = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='gsr2',
        null=True,
        blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Gespanne'

    def clean(self):
        # validation methods


class GameRequest(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Spiel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sr1 = models.ForeignKey(
            CustomUser,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='sr1',
            null=True,
            blank=True)
    sr2 = models.ForeignKey(
            CustomUser,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            related_name='sr2',
            null=True,
            blank=True)
    refTeam= models.ForeignKey(
            RefTeam,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            null=True,
            blank=True)
    STATI = (
        ('DC', 'Declined'),
        ('OP', 'Open'),
        ('AP', 'Approved')
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATI, max_length=9, default='OP')


    def clean(self):
        # at least sr1, sr2 or team
        # not team and single ref
        # ...


class Appointment(models.Model):
    game = models.OneToOneField(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    appointed = models.OneToOneField(GameRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: can you share your existing model structure?

Comment: I am open for a complete restructure if it makes it easy to use and to maintan.

Comment: I could remove the Appointment model but then I cant use ForeignKeys to reference the Game from Request and vice versa. And if I only use the Status in Request, I have to make sure that only one Request is approved, while many can be open or declined ==> unique_together is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Each UserModel is represents a single Referee**

For That i will use a OneToOne:

```
class Referee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

**A RefereeTeam is made of two Referees**

For that i will have a ForeignKey on Referee and a Model `RefereeTeam`

```
class Referee(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        referee_team = models.ForeignKey(
            RefereeTeam, 
            blank=True, 
            null=True, 
            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class RefereeTeam(models.Model):
    WHAT YOU WANT FIELDS
```

And dont forget that `RefereeTeam` object have reverse relation to `Referee` with `obj.referee_set`

**One Game can have one referee or a RefereeTeam**

It's a little more tricky but here a solution (not the best IMO) that will return you a `Referee` or a `RefereeTeam` model (more info about [generic relations here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)):

```
class Game(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

**A Referee or a RefereeTeam can request any Game (to supervise it)**

Same model than the previous question.

**Each Game can have arbitrary Requests**

```
class Requests(models.Model):
        game = models.ForeignKey(
            Game, 
            blank=False, 
            null=False, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        request = models.CharField(
            max_length=255, blank=False, 
            null=False)
```

**Each Game can have only one appointed Referee or Team
States are ('Declined', 'Open', 'Appointed') for each request**

I dont really understant this one